# Drawing tool for evacuation plan?

Tags: software-recommendation

I've tried to draw the plan with dia, gimp and inkscape, but that was too dificult for me. Is there better drawing tool for that?

Answer (score 5):

Try OpenOffice/LibreOffice Draw. It is installed by default, in the Graphics menu.

Answer (score 3):

A [CAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_design) tool would be most appropriate. I played around with [PythonCAD](http://pythoncad.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/doku.php), [SagCAD](http://sagcad.sourceforge.jp/en/overview.html), and [QCad Community Edition](http://www.qcad.org/qcad.html) to see what they were like:

- Drawing in PythonCAD was straightforward, but it had trouble printing or exporting to a printable format.
- SagCAD's interface came across as bizarre and unintuitive. It looks like it's more oriented toward 3D sketching.
- QCad Community Edition worked well. I suggest giving it a try.

All of these are available in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 2):

A ruler and a pen? Inkscape is the easiest IMO

http://vimeo.com/21324813